# c++ switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

whenever I try to use switch with

```
case myvar:
```

where myvar is a char I get an error. Is it possible to make it work? Thanks

Comment: -1 For saying you get an error without saying what the error is.

Answer (score 9):

The expressions used in cases must be constant integral expressions that can be evaluated at compile time.  So no.  Unless `myvar` is a `static const int` of some sort, you can't make this work using `case`.

But what you can do is just use chained `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. Cases must be compile-time constants.

Comment: Not just compile-time constants, but *integral* compile-time constants.  For example, `case "someval" :` will never work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want your switch cases to work based on char. As others said, your switch cases should be integral compile-time constants. And the below example works because, the corresponding ASCII values are retrieved for each case of char.

```
#include <iostream>
int main( void )
{
    char myvar = 'a' ;
    switch( myvar )
    {
        case 'a':
            std::cout << "\n This Works !" << std::endl ;
            break ;
        default:
            break ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Hope this helps !